# Access to file on Hadoop Virtualbox Cluster

Tags: linux, hadoop

I have problem with get file from Host machine (windows) from hadoop cluster working on virtualbox Ubuntu.

I see cluster from host machine ( http://192.168.56.105:8088/cluster), and java script see folder structure on hdfs, but when i try read file i get this error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP-1570018429-127.0.0.1-1484660807169:blk_1073742497_1673 file=/Item/part-r-00000
```

When i run this same script on cluster vmbox ubuntu i get file and correct.

Probably problem is namenode try search data on different place(_1673?), when ip or user is different - but i can't find right configuration of this issue.

Thanks for advice.

Linux user: wukkie

This is script:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;

public class InsertReommendationToDB {

    private static Configuration getConfiguration(){
        Configuration conf = new Configuration(); 
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.56.105:54310/" );      
        conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "wukkie");
        return conf;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){     
        try {

            UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createProxyUser("wukkie", UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser()); 
            ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {


                Path filepath = new Path("/Item/part-r-00000");             
                public Void run() throws Exception {

                    FileSystem fs = filepath.getFileSystem( getConfiguration() );

                    FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(filepath);
                    String line; 
                    line = inputStream.readLine();

                    while(line != null){
                        System.out.println(line);
                        line = inputStream.readLine();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find reason and workaround solution.

**Hadoop work in that way:**

1. Application ask namenode about file
2. Namenode send a information about datanode(s) which stored a requested file -and get address of datanode.
3. Application ask datanode(s) on received url(s) about file and get filestream.

**Virtualbox and host architecure issue.**

Virtualbox hadoop launch datanode on address /localhost:50070/. When host application ask namenode about file, get local address of datanode "localhost:50070". That result in application try get file from unseen address.

**Workaround solution**

1) We need get address of virtualbox machine ( i use host-only addapter in virtualbox connection settings). 
ifconfig | grep addr

I get address **192.168.56.104**

2) We can set now a reverse proxy on host machine (windows). Start cmd with admin rights and put

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=50070 listenaddress=localhost connectport=50070 connectaddress=192.168.56.104
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=50020 listenaddress=localhost connectport=50020 connectaddress=192.168.56.104
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=50090 listenaddress=localhost connectport=50090 connectaddress=192.168.56.104
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=50010 listenaddress=localhost connectport=50010 connectaddress=192.168.56.104
```

Now when host application get localhost:50010 address of datanode, proxy to client machine.

Comment: This seems like a solution that can work out for me. However, I work on mac, do you know by chance how can I do this on mac? Or maybe can you please tell at least what I should look for. Thank you.